# Why does this Razor syntax gives compilation errors?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I either get a "you need a ; here" or a "best overloaded match has invalid arguments" errors.

```
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            @for (int i = 0; i < startDay; ++i)
            {
                @:<td><span></span><span></span></td>
            }
            @for (int j = startDay; j < ((numberOfDays + startDay) - 1); ++j)
            {
                <td>
                    <span>@startCount</span>
                    <br />
                    <span>
                        @{
                            var todaysEvents = Model.ToList().FindAll(d => d.CalDate.Day == j);
                            foreach(HTMLMVCCalendar.Models.CalendarModel eventsToday in todaysEvents)
                            {
                                foreach(HTMLMVCCalendar.Models.EventModel eventToday in eventsToday.CalEvents)
                                {
                                    @eventToday.DayCode.ToString // error here
                                    @:<br />
                                    @eventToday.Subject // error here
                                    @:<br />
                                    @eventToday.EventDesc //error here
                                } 
                                @:<br /> 
                            }
                        }
                    </span>
                </td>
                if ((j + 1) % 7 == 0)
                {
                    @:</tr><tr>
                }
                @++startCount;
            }
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `<text>` element rather than using the `@` before every piece of text you want to display.  Convert:

```
foreach(HTMLMVCCalendar.Models.EventModel eventToday in eventsToday.CalEvents)
{
    @eventToday.DayCode.ToString // error here
    @:<br />
    @eventToday.Subject // error here
    @:<br />
    @eventToday.EventDesc //error here
}
```

To:

```
foreach(HTMLMVCCalendar.Models.EventModel eventToday in eventsToday.CalEvents)
{
    <text>
        @eventToday.DayCode:<br />
        @eventToday.Subject:<br />
        @eventToday.EventDesc
    </text>
}
```

I also removed the `.ToString` (which was missing the parentheses) because objects are converted to strings implicitly when using the `@` symbol.

Another thing, you have this code:

```
@{
    var todaysEvents = Model.ToList().FindAll(d => d.CalDate.Day == j);
    foreach(HTMLMVCCalendar.Models.EventModel eventToday in eventsToday.CalEvents) 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

This needlessly increases your nesting.  Contrary to our intuition, Razor blocks that begin with `@` do not actually form a closed scope like it would in C#.  Therefore, you can write it as:

```
@{
    var todaysEvents = Model.ToList().FindAll(d => d.CalDate.Day == j);
}
@foreach(HTMLMVCCalendar.Models.EventModel eventToday in todaysEvents.CalEvents) 
{
    ...
}
```

As you can see (if you run it), `todaysEvents` is still accessible.